# Java not connecting to database

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm trying to get my java code to connect to the database. I swear it was connecting a few hours ago and suddenly it's not. I have reinstalled, restarted xampp, eclipse my laptop. I even uninstalled and reinstalled mysql.

Here's my .java file:

```
import java.sql.DriverManager;

import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;
import com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource;

public class Connect_db {
//  private static final String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sjsu";
//  private static final String user = "root";
//  private static final String password = ""; 
//
//  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
//      java.sql.Connection con = null;
//      try {
//          Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
//          con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
//          // commented since doesn't exists in Java 6
//          // System.out.println(con.getSchema());
//          System.out.println(con.getCatalog());
//      } finally {
//          con.close();
//      }
//  }
    private static MysqlDataSource ds = null;

    public static MysqlDataSource getDataSource(String db_name) {
        if (ds == null) {
            // db variables set here
            getDataSource("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306", "root", "", 3306);
        }
        ds.setDatabaseName(db_name);
        return ds;
    }

    private static void getDataSource(String db_url, String db_user, String db_password, int db_port) {
        try {
            ds = new MysqlDataSource();
            ds.setServerName(db_url);
            ds.setUser(db_user);
            ds.setPassword(db_password);
            ds.setPort(db_port);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("MysqlDataSource err: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

My .jsp file

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>atozknowledge.com demo Regjsp</title>
</head>
<body>
<%@ page import ="java.sql.*" %>
<%@ page import ="javax.sql.*" %>
<%
String user=request.getParameter("userid"); 
session.putValue("userid",user); 
String pwd=request.getParameter("pwd"); 
String fname=request.getParameter("fname"); 
String lname=request.getParameter("lname"); 
String email=request.getParameter("email"); 
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 

java.sql.Connection con = Connect_db.getDataSource("sjsu").getConnection();

Statement st= con.createStatement(); 
ResultSet rs; 
int i=st.executeUpdate("insert into users values ('"+user+"','"+pwd+"','"+fname+"', '"+lname+"','"+email+"')"); 

out.println("Registered"); 


%>
<a href="index.html">Home</a>
</body>
</html>
```

My html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>atozknowledge.com demo Registration</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="reg.jsp" method="post">

User name :<input type="text" name="userid" /><br/><br/>
password :<input type="password" name="pwd" /><br/><br/>
First name :<input type="text" name="fname" /><br/><br/>
Last name :<input type="text" name="lname" /><br/><br/>
Email :<input type="text" name="email" /><br/><br/>
<br/><br/>

<input type="submit" />

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The error

[image: Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.]

It used to be able to put the userid, pwd, ... etc in my database and now it can't.

Comment: Please post exception message as text, not as screenshots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error states, it cannot find the class `Connect_db`. You need to add an explicit import for `Connect_db` to your JSP, that is add:

```
<%@ page import ="package.of.Connect_db" %>
```

Querying directly from JSP is a poor choice, your should separate getting the data from displaying the data.

Tomcat also provides support for creating and registering data sources, use that instead of rolling your own. Especially, as `MysqlDataSource` doesn't provide connection pooling.

And finally, concatenating values into your query string is **unsafe**, especially with user provided input, as it leaves you open to SQL injection. Instead you should use a prepared statement with parameters. Please take a look at Using [Prepared Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) in the JDBC tutorial.

Comment: I added the page import, and it still doesnt work, same result.

Comment: @a123 `Connect_db` is in a package? If not, move it to a package. and make sure you use that package in the import. And if that still doesn't work, please update your question to show the layout of your project.

Comment: I put it in a package and I used prepared statements, it works now! Thanks!!

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you instead of giving the my.jsp inn the from action it is better to use a servlet. Maybe it can solve your. Create a new servlet and write your code inside of post method.

Comment: This is a comment. not an answer